# Conversion of Varchar Data type to a datetime datatype resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I'm having problem with my SQL Question. I have two columns with dates. FinDt and DesProDt which is Int. Sometimes FinDt is 0, and sometimes DesProDt is 0. I need to check if they are 0 from beginning. If any of those is 0, then i want to show 0, otherwise i want to do a dateDiff between the two dates to get a value.

```
CASE WHEN (CAST(F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt AS VARCHAR) = 0 
     OR CAST(F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt AS VARCHAR) = 0) 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE DATEDIFF(D , CONVERT (datetime , CONVERT (varchar , F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt)) , CONVERT (datetime , CONVERT (varchar , F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt))) 
END
```

I don't understand what i am doing wrong. I get an error where it says Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime datatype resulted in an out-of-range value.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Date in varchar and probably different format 2015-01-21 or 2015-21-01. Try `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` or `mdy`

Comment: "what i am doing wrong" - storing dates as `int` is wrong. If you explain how exactly you store dates as `int`, somebody would be able to help you.

Comment: Also you compare the result of a cast to varchar against an int: why? Compare it with the string '0' instead.

Comment: I'm working against a business system and they decided to store a date as an int so i cannot change this. I tried to change the 0 to '0' but it didn't work. If i delete the Case part, then the datediff works until it finds a post where the date is 0. So i know that part is working. The dates are stored as int in this format 20151106.

Comment: Why are you casting them to varchar in your first case?

Comment: Either all the data fails, or there is one or more rows that have invalid data.  You will need to figure it out with some more troubleshooting. Maybe post some data from those columns.

Comment: When you convert from `int` to `varchar` you should specify explicitly the `varchar` size. Since you are storing dates without time you should be converting to `date`, not `datetime`. When you convert from `varchar` to `date` you should specify explicitly the style that matches the format of your data. And, of course you can have invalid data, like `123456789` in your `int` column, which doesn't represent any date.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried it, but i cannot get it to work. I need a CASE statement that checks if the two columns are more than 0. How can i do this? All i do seems to fail.

Comment: Why are you casting as varchar and then comparing to an INT ? And check the date format.  You didn't specify so it's using the default. It could be that the data you are receiving doesn't fit. And you need when converting to varchar and/or date to add the format/mask.

Comment: I solved it thanks to all of your help! There was a date with 1013, instead of 2013. Then the number of Days became too big to handle for an int value when you do a datediff. Thank you all! Here is the last code.

CASE WHEN CAST(F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt AS INT) <> 0 AND 
                      CAST(F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt AS INT) <> 0 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(DD, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt), 112)), 
                      CONVERT(date, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt), 112))) AS INT) ELSE 0 END AS [Dagar Sen]

Answer (score 0):

You have one or more values that is not valid.  You have to find them.  They will be at the beginning or end of a sort.

```
select F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt from table order by F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt  
select F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt    from table order by F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it out and see what i will get for results!

Comment: I Tried the above, and all fields are either 0, or have a date like "20150101" I modified the code to look like this, but it doesnt work too. 

    CASE WHEN (F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt <> 0 AND F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt <> 0) THEN ISNULL(CAST(DATEDIFF(D, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), F0001.dbo.OrdLn.DesProDt), 112)), CONVERT(date, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), F0001.dbo.OrdLn.FinDt), 112))) AS INT), 0) END AS [Dagar Sen]

Comment: Loop it an find the failure.  I seriously doubt a date like "20150101" is going to fail.

Comment: So all fields are 0 or have a date like 20150101 but the problem was 1013?

Comment: I had one post with date 10130112 instead of 20130112 so i correct that and it work!

Comment: So then how was this not the answer?  Did that sort some how fail to put the 1013 before 2013?

Comment: the problem was with the compairing of two dates. If you compare date 1 10130112 with date 2 20130117 then it is about  365 000 days and integer should be between -32768 to 32768

Comment: No shit that was problem.  Did 1013 sort before 2013?  Yes or no?